# PCRE and Python regex not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex, `/\[([^]]+)\]\((((?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?.*?)\)/gm`, works fine in [PCRE](http://regex101.com/r/mS5lX4) and [Python](http://regex101.com/r/oD5uE8), but not so much in [javascript](http://regex101.com/r/uH9jP1).

Why not? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping `]` inside `[...]` will make it work in Javascript:

```
\[([^\]]+)\]\((((?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?.*?)\)
     ^^
```

Comment: Interesting, is Javascript just more picky or is there a reason the designers chose the need for escaping?

Comment: @Justin808, I don't know the reason behind. Some regular expression engines are smart enough to handle that, others are not. For another example: Some regular expression complain about `{abc}`, others don't complain and just match `{abc}` literally.